# Add types for passing a ref state setter from parent to child with TypeScript in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I lost some hours and don't get this. I tried a ton of examples, but nothing worked. How do I solve these sort of challenges? How do I know what kind of types Typescript wants for those things, and why the hell should ANYONE do such things with typescript, since in JS it just works!

I just want to pass my useState from parent to the child, and there I want to set a Ref of a div to the useState so that the parent can manipulate the div (and its children).

```
const Parent: React.FC<iParent> = ({title}) => {
    
    const x = React.useRef() as React.MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement>;;
    const refSetter = useState(x);

  return(
       <Child setMyRef={refSetter} />
  )

}



interface iChild {
  setMyRef: Dispatch<SetStateAction<React.MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement>>>;
}
const Child: React.FC<iChild> = ({setMyRef}) => {
  
  const myRef = useRef(???type?);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if(myRef.current){
        setMyRef(myRef);
    }
  }, [])

  return(
       <div ref={myRef} />
  )

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as below. A way to know what type for what variable is to read the error you get and also what you see when you hover over one.

```js
import {Dispatch, FC, RefObject, SetStateAction, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

interface iChild {
  setMyRef: Dispatch<SetStateAction<RefObject<HTMLDivElement> | null>>;
}
const Child: FC<iChild> = ({ setMyRef }) => {
  const myRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setMyRef(myRef);
  }, []);

  return <div ref={myRef} />;
};

const Parent: FC<iParent> = ({ title }) => {
  const [ref, refSetter] = useState<RefObject<HTMLDivElement> | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(ref?.current);
  }, [ref, ref?.current]);

  return <Child setMyRef={refSetter} />;
};
```

[image: Edit on CodeSanbox]

Comment: I see thx! I hovered over the myRef and it showed me that it has to be Dispatch<SetStateAction<React.MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement>>>... but ok.  I think you did there on useEffect a small mistake, it shouldn't listen to setMyRef. It should listen to myRef or some other changes which happens on the div of child. Another thing I noticed when you useEffect on ref in Parent even when the setMyRef() in Child was called nothing happens.

Comment: I see.  And about why nothing is happening, try logging `ref.current` in an `useEffect` in the parent that has `reft` as dependency. I edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you worked! the thing is when you listen to ref - the content of the div may change, but the div itself stays the same, so also the ref and ref.current - so you must listen to the content change of the div and not to the ref of the div. thx.

Comment: Yeah right. I didn't have the hole picture of what you were trying to do, other than the type part. Thanks for the feedback ! I edited my answer.